# How do I add a new field using conditional expression?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm currently using Django and its in-built database. Assuming in the models.py file, I have a class called User:

```
class User(models.Model):
    RACE = [
        ('0', 'Black'),
        ('1', 'White'),
        ('2', 'Asian'),
        ('3', 'Hispanic'),
        ('4', 'Others'),
    ]
    ASIAN = [
        ('0', 'Chinese'),
        ('1', 'India'),
        ('2', 'Filipino'),
        ('3', 'Japanese'),
        ('4', 'Korean'),
        ('5', 'Vietnamese'),
        ('6', 'Others'),        
    ]
    
    HISPANIC = [
        ('0', 'Mexican'),
        ('1', 'Puerto_Rican'),
        ('2', 'Others'),
    ]
    race = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = RACE, null=True) 
    sub_race = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = ASIAN, null=True) if race == 'Asian' else (models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = HISPANIC, null=True) if race == 'Hispanic' else '0')
```

I was hoping to create a field called sub_race, where its value depends on race. Nonetheless, the above method does not work. Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: Have you considered adding these as a foreign keys to keep your data normalized?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to do it. The reason why I didn't try that out was because I want all default values to be 0. And if the race is either hispanic or asian, then there will be new pop out and new values associated with it.

Comment: @RofyRafy Keep in mind models are used to store data not the application logic, you might need to re-approach your problem in different angle.

Comment: As @Orville points out too, it would be best to store these in your database (for data validation purposes) and most likely add the application logic to your views.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to implement them